# Error while updating Ubuntu server : no space left on device

Tags: 16.04, server, update-manager, vmware, disk-usage

I just installed Ubuntu server 16.04 on VMware esxi. while updating Ubuntu server, it shows an error `No space left on device`. More details in the following screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You didn't allocate enough disk space (*no space left on device* it reports). Allocate more space, or if you believe you did allocate enough space you should provide details of what space (to what mount point) you allocated.  Also your 'picture' is of text, please copy & paste text into your question as its easier to read & 'paste' into browser or back to you in command/answers.

Comment: Not enough space was allocated for the VM. Can you run from inside the VM: df -h And paste the results? This will show all of the mounted filesystems including their total space and free space. From there, you can figure out where more space needs to be allocated.

Comment: The GUI tool for examining where disk space is being used is called baobab (because of The Little Prince having to deal with Baobab trees growing too big to fast). Try using that to find where your disk is full.